# Is there a way to find out if a retrieved component is dynamic/publishable using core service?

Tags: 2011, core-service, publishing

Is there a way to find out if a retrieved component is dynamic/publishable using core service ?
I am not able to see any property that can tell me that .

Please help.

Comment: Consider flipping the requirement by starting with a dynamic template rather than the items, especially if you want this information for many components.

Answer (score 8):

The component by itself can't be nor dynamic nor static, it's component presentation that can be dynamic. It's controlled by `IsRepositoryPublishable` property per `ComponentTemplateData`

Comment: +1. We publish pages and component presentations rather than components.

Answer (score 4):

As user978511 noted, it's not the component which determines whether publishing is dynamic, but the component template. Using the core service, you can retrieve a `ComponentTemplateData` object and check its `IsRepositoryPublishable` property.

`ComponentTemplateData` also has a `RelatedSchemas` property, so with a bit more code you could find out whether a given component is based on a schema for which there is a dynamic template.

If there is at least one dynamic component template, you will be able to publish the component. Publishing the component will result in a component presentation being published for each of the dynamic component templates related to the schema.

Comment: Or you can publish the dynamic template(s) itself apart from Pages and components

Answer (score 2):

If it is highly required to know if the component can be used as a DCP I can think of two ways to achieve this, though it will be pretty expensive operation.

1. `CoreServiceClient.ResolveItems` should resolve the component if it has any dynamic component templates.
2. This is a two step approach, first getting a list of component templates using `Publication.Get(List)ComponentTemplates` and then checking if any of the templates is dynamic.