# How to see if a Component Template is a Dynamic Component Template in TOM.NET?

Tags: tom.net

What property on a TOM.NET `Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.ComponentTemplate` shows if the template is a dynamic template or a static one? In the CME GUI this is set in the *Component Presentations based on this Component Template will be:* field.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It is in `ComponentTemplate.IsRepositoryPublishable`. Once you know the name it makes sense. From the API doc:

> public bool IsRepositoryPublishable { get; set; }
>
> A "dynamic" Component Presentation is published separately instead of
>   being embedded on a Page.

The checkbox *Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly* is in `ComponentTemplate.AllowOnPage`, that one is a bit easier to find.

Comment: Hmm, now I know the property name and search for it I found http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2604/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-a-retrieved-component-is-dynamic-publishable-using/2605#2605 which gives a hint for the same property in Core Service.